# Why the encoder isn't giving a proper square wave?

Tags: digital-logic, dc-motor, encoder

I have two encoders. As it can be seen below, one of them gives a proper square wave but the other doesn't.

[image]

What could be the reason for such behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: Channel 1 on AC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you haven't enabled AC coupling on your oscilloscope for CH1. It looks like there's an RC decay on each cycle of your encoder, which would fit with AC coupling on the oscilloscope.

Answer (score 1):

There's high-pass filter somewhere. It can be your oscilloscope or probe in AC mode or the encoder itself has a series capacitor.

You are the only who can find, where.